# DAX: How to achieve the effect of a join/relationship between a bitmask column and a table of bit values?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a table CarHistoryFact (CarHistoryFactId, CarId, CarHistoryFactTime, CarHistoryFactConditions) that tracks the historical status of cars. CarHistoryFactConditions is a 25-bit (in binary) int column that encodes the status of 25 various conditions the car may be in at a given point in time.

I have a dimension table CarConditions with a row for each of the conditions, and their base 10 bit value.

How can I implement a "relationship" between the fact and dimension, giving a list of all the conditions a given car is

I can come up with bit parsing code, but I'm not sure how to hook it up to the dimension table to get just the currently applicable conditions at a car-time.

Bitmask parsing in dax can be seen here :

https://radacad.com/quick-dax-convert-number-to-binary

Comment: Even if it's possible, this will be a very complicated and hard to use model. I would simply convert each CarHistoryFact record into 25 records (Car, Time, Condition), connect to dimensions and be done with it. Your fact table will increase 25x, but it will have rather low cardinality and should perform well.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but I know that often times there are "slick" solutions in dax and wanted to explore that possibility a well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a CROSSJOIN Table where all records are added 25 times and then filter out the once not existing

```
CarHistoryConditions = 
var temp = CROSSJOIN(CarHistoryFact ; CarConditions )
return FILTER(temp; MOD(TRUNC(CarHistoryFact [CarHistoryFactConditions] / CarConditions [bit]):2) = 1)
```

note: I assumed the CarHistoryFactConditions and bit to be an integer, not a string of bits. For sure you can change that.

The reult is a table with as many rows of conditions for each car. E.g. Car one has 2 conditions and Car two has 5 conditions. You get 7 rows

Comment: Yep - the actual fact condition data is int: 2049 indicates conditions 1 and 12 are happening (1-based counting). Thank you for the idea of starting with the entire universe of possibility and then filtering to the ones that are actually in play. I'll give it a try and see what performance is like!

Comment: @sherifffruitfly- how'd it go?